# Dropping an adx table with the azurerm terraform provider

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, adx

How does one drop an adx table using the azurerm terraform provider? It seems like an intentional exclusion, so I wonder if I'm missing something fundamental here.

I tried doing the following:

```
resource "azurerm_kusto_script" "drop_old_table" {
  name                       = "drop_old_table"
  database_id                = azurerm_kusto_database.mydb.id
  continue_on_errors_enabled = false
  script_content             = ".drop tables ( Table1, Table2) ifexists"
}
```

But got an error:

> Code="ScriptContainsUnsupportedCommand" Message="[BadRequest] The provided script contains unsupported command. The commands must start with the following verbs: '.create, .create-or-alter, .create-merge, .alter, .alter-merge, .enable'"

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to drop the table if exists:***

***code:***

```
resource "azurerm_kusto_script" "example" {
  name                               = "example"
  database_id                        = azurerm_kusto_database.mydb.id
  url                                = azurerm_storage_blob.newexample.id
  sas_token                          = data.azurerm_storage_account_blob_container_sas.example.sas
  continue_on_errors_enabled         = true
  force_an_update_when_value_changed = "first"
}
```

Using

```
source_content= ".drop table MyTable ifexists"
```

***Received the same error :***

```
Scripts/drop_old_table" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_kusto_script" for more information.
```

error:

[image]

Terraform may not work while cheking using ifexists query .

I used .drop table MyTable excluding the ifexists
When I checked the portal , I could not find anytable.

```
.drop table MyTable
```

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "newexample" {
  name                   = "script.txt"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.newexample.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.conexample.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source_content         = ".drop table MyTable "
}
```

As drop requies to check the resource first, gave error:

To query for pre existing resource, you may have to use variables to store data and use Boolean state.

or try use external data_source ,if can be done using sdk or powershell cli [terraform-check-if-resource-exists-before-creating-it | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689512/terraform-check-if-resource-exists-before-creating-it)

**Reference** : [.drop table and .drop tables - Azure Data Explorer | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/drop-table-command)

Comment: Thanks for answering! So did the drop command without ifexists execute successfully via azurerm?

Comment: No , it gave an error too when i rechecked .We may need to make use of external data_source as in the reference attached