# I need Terraform to retrieve a Network data by name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

I need to retrieve data of an existing or not Network and if it's not then it should be created i need to integrate this script in CI/CD pipeline

this is my code

```
data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "existed_network" {
  name          = "Network-name"
}

resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "edums_network" {
  count  = data.openstack_networking_network_v2.existed_network.[*].id == "" ? 1:0
  name   = "Network-name"
}
```

i end up with this error when the network is not created
Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known issue (discussed for instance in [Data sources should allow empty results without failing #16380](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380), [Terraform Data with No Results](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-data-with-no-results/47228/2) or here: [Terraform check if resource exists before creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689512/terraform-check-if-resource-exists-before-creating-it)).

In Terraform, data sources are used to retrieve details about external resources, which are not managed by Terraform itself. Essentially, data sources act as a link between the existing infrastructure and the intended configuration, facilitating a more adaptive and context-aware approach to provisioning.

Terraform does not support empty data sources:

> *In general data sources will fail if the resource being requested doesn’t exist. They are expected to be used to reference resources that are not managed by Terraform (or by a different Terraform root module/state).*

(from https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-data-with-no-results/47228/2)

### Conditional Creation of Objects

Terraform recommends to use variables.

Quotes from [Conditional Creation of Objects](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition#conditional-creation-of-objects):

> *Rather than trying to write a module that itself tries to detect whether something exists and create it if not, we recommend applying the dependency inversion approach: making the module accept the object it needs as an argument, via an input variable.*

> *This is consistent with Terraform's declarative style: rather than creating modules with complex conditional branches, we directly describe what should already exist and what we want Terraform to manage itself.*

### Solution

For this case (creating a network in OpenStack only if it does not already exist) there are two possible approaches, either using a variable or with `import`.

#### With a variable

```
variable "existing_network_name" {
  description = "Name of existing or to-be-created network in Terraform."
  default      = null
 }


resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "edums_network" {
count  = var.existing_network_name == null ? 1:0
name   = "Network-name"
}
```

Define the variable in `terraform.tfvars`:

```
existing_network_name = "Network-name"
```

or pass it as a command-line argument:

```
terraform apply -var existing_network_name = "Network-name"
```

#### With `import`

`openstack_networking_network_v2` supports `import` using the existing network's id (see [Terraform Openstack provider documentation for networking_network_v2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-))

With an `import` block:

```
import {
  to = openstack_networking_network_v2.edums_network
  id = "i-abcd1234"
}


resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "edums_network" {
  name   = "Network-name"
}
```

Again, the network ID must exist; otherwise, Terraform will generate an error message.